# Using PIG and Java udf : A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: VERY WEIRD CHARACTER Unicode::UTF8Encoding::Case

Tags: java, utf-8, apache-pig

I am using a java library to parse text to longitude and latitude. 
Through PIG I send a text in each line and it returns a longitude and latitude (if found),
otherwise null.

The library works fine but it crashes terribly when it finds very weird characters. 
The error I get is (I will show your an example of the word character at the end) :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x02d927da, pid=4880, tid=4151524208
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libPlacemakerJNI.so+0x4f47da] 
YGEO::TokeniserBase::CaseCollector::add(YGEO::Unicode::UTF8Encoding::Case)+0x46
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core
dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/grid0/tmp/bz6784883/hs_err_pid4880.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

An example of the weird character (which overlaps other lines) even when you search 
in google is this one https://www.google.es/#q=++%3B̋̉ͧ̇

I can not even copy and paste it here...

Does any one have an idea how can I filter these case before sending the lines to the udf? 
I will greatly appreciate any help.

--- edited :

some people asked me to add my code. 
I am not very sure if it is important since all I want to know is how to filter these characters in Pig, Java or with any other user defined function before passing it to placemaker.... 
so here it goes:

```
register /homes/ruthgavi/JARS/placemaker_java.jar;
register /homes/ruthgavi/JARS/internetlocality-for-placemaker-1.2.0.jar;
register /homes/ruthgavi/JARS/placemaker_bootstrap-1.2.0.jar;
register /homes/ruthgavi/JARS/PlacemakerUDF-1.2.0.jar;
define placemaker com.yahoo.geo.placemaker.pig_udf.Placemaker('YGeo_Demo1-871687');
define documents com.yahoo.geo.placemaker.pig_udf.GetDocuments();

SET job.name '3.1.Placemaker.pig';
set default_parallel 500;


-- LOAD LOCATIONS ONLY
A = Load '$input1' USING PigStorage() as (location:chararray);
A = FILTER A by location is not null;

-- TRYING TO FILTER TO AVOID MISTAKES
A = FILTER A by SIZE(TRIM(location))>1;
A= FILTER A by not (location matches '[^\\x00-\\x7F]'); -- not (not ascii characters);


--- FINDING LOCATIONS ALREADY IN LONG AND LAT FORMAT
B = FILTER  A BY (location matches '.T:([0-9]|" "|-).*') --or (location matches '[NS].([0-9]|" "|-).*') 
            or (location matches 'iPhone:.*') or (location matches 'iphone:.*') or  (location matches '([0-9]|-[0-9]).[^a-zA-Z]*') ;
B = FOREACH B GENERATE location, REGEX_EXTRACT(location, '(.*)\\:(.*)\\,(.*)', 2) as latitude, REGEX_EXTRACT(location, '(.*)\\:(.*)\\,(.*)', 3) as longitude ;
LOCATIONSTOTALUT = FILTER B by latitude is not null and longitude is not null;
LOCATIONSTOTALUT = FOREACH LOCATIONSTOTALUT GENERATE location, (double) latitude, (double) longitude;
LOCATIONSTOTALUT = FILTER LOCATIONSTOTALUT BY latitude !=0.0 and longitude!=0.0;
LOCATIONSTOTALUT = FOREACH LOCATIONSTOTALUT GENERATE location, latitude, longitude, 'UT' as flag; 



--- PASSING TEXT
LOCATIONSFIXED = FILTER  A BY NOT(location matches '.T:.*') -- and  NOT (location matches '[NS].([0-9]|" "|-).*') 
                            and NOT(location matches 'iPhone:.*') 
                            and NOT(location matches 'iphone:.*') and NOT(location matches '([0-9]|-[0-9]).[^a-zA-Z]*');

LOCATIONSFIXED4 = foreach LOCATIONSFIXED  generate location,   flatten(documents(placemaker('plain/text',location)));
LOCATIONSFIXED4 = FILTER LOCATIONSFIXED4 by SIZE ($1) > 0;

LOCATIONSFIXED5 = filter LOCATIONSFIXED4 by administrativeScope.centroid.$0 != 0.0 and --latitude
                                            administrativeScope.centroid.$1 != 0.0; -- longitude
LOCATIONSFOUND = foreach LOCATIONSFIXED5 generate   location,
                                            administrativeScope.centroid.$0 as latitude,
                                            administrativeScope.centroid.$1 as longitude;           
LOCATIONSFOUND = FOREACH LOCATIONSFOUND  GENERATE location, latitude, longitude, 'TEXT' as flag;


-- SAVING ALL LOCATIONS FOUND
LOCATIONSTOINTERNETLOCALITY= UNION LOCATIONSFOUND, LOCATIONSTOTALUT;
--store LOCATIONSTOINTERNETLOCALITY into '/tmp/FOUNDCOORDINATESinAXONITE.bz2';
--store LOCATIONSTOINTERNETLOCALITY into '/tmp/ruth/PLACEMAKER_LASTTWEETS_2013.bz2';
STORE LOCATIONSTOINTERNETLOCALITY into '$output1';
```

Comment: Well it looks like the problme is in the JNI part - it sounds like you should file a bug with libPlacemaker.

Comment: Thank you, I did asked for help and they are looking at the problem. Since they are taking so long (maybe busy in other things), I was wondering if there is an easy solution to filter such characters before using placemaker.

Comment: Well it's hard to suggest a solution without seeing *any* of your code.

Comment: I use the library in Pig like this :

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit it into your question.

Comment: OK I did that already.

Comment: So you don't have any Java code at all?

Comment: I do not know what is behind the placemaker library.  All I know is that it works for many cases even in chinese,arabic, etc. It is just recently that I cam across those weird characters which make the library to crash ....

Comment: Okay, I don't think we've got enough of an idea of your architecture to understand what we can actually do here - at least, I don't. I suggest you give more details about how it all hangs together. Note that it's very likely that the fix involves getting in *before* you've already got characters - when you read the data from a file (or wherever it's coming from).

Comment: Joop Eggen gave me an idea, I could build a udf with his suggestion and use it in PIG before using Placemaker. Will try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One might convert the wrong UTF-8 data file to a correct UTF-8 data file in java.
Use [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) which has error handling.

```
byte[] bytes = ...
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);  
CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();  
utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);  
utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);  
CharBuffer charBuf = utf8Decoder.decode(byteBuf);
```

Of course you need to find the problem's cause; maybe a wrong encoding or the C api only treats the old UTF-8 standard of at most 3 bytes in a multibyte sequence.

Comment: Thanks. Will this eliminate also characters in other languages like Chinese or arabic?  In my case, I want to keep those characters and "only" eliminate the weird characters such as the one in the example.

Comment: To keep only Windows Latin-1 use `Charsets.from("Windows-1252").newDecoder()`. Mind, also look for more in-depth usage otherwere.